# のなんのって and variations

Tags: grammar, words

**Do the structures のなんのって, のなんのと and のなんのといって / のなんのと言って refer to the same and can be used interchangeably? If so, is there also any other variation of のなんのって that can be used in the same way?**

A time ago, I learned that のなんのって is used to emphasize the degree of an adjective or a verb.

「おいしいのなんのって」=「とてもおいしい」

Source: https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=35053

However, now I've found the structures のなんのと and のなんのといって / のなんのと言って, which look like variations of のなんのって, but **whereas in some sites I see them to be actually emphasizing an adjective**

ふかいのなんのといって、どんなにながく綱をおろしても底にとどかないというくらいふかいのです。（「人魚のひいさま」より）

Source: https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000019/files/42383_21527.html

**in other sites they seem to have a different usage, that is, "speaking loudly, annoyingly".**

https://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE-nonannno.html

**Then I wonder if in reality のなんのって, のなんのと and のなんのといって / のなんのと言って are the same, and the meaning "speaking loudly, annoyingly" is just a contextual interpretation of the emphasis of an adjective or verb or these structures are not related with each other and they have different meanings and usages.**

Comment: Related?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6879/9831

Comment: No. Although のなんのって is explained, it does not answer my doubts, I think.